# Sending ALT-codes using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I find no way to send an ALT-code to an application, for example Notepad

```
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto.keyboard import SendKeys, KeySequenceError

app = application.Application()
app.start("Notepad.exe")
SendKeys("%(234)")
```

This displays "34" to the screen.
How can I send the ALT-code for Omega to Notepad?

Comment: It will be possible in pywinauto==0.6.6 (currently in master branch). Example: {VK_MENU down}234{VK_MENU up}.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html), the `send_keys` method supports unicode characters. So, you should in that case be able to simply do `SendKeys('Ω')`. I can't test this myself at the moment but I don't see why that wouldn't work.